# Clion. How to start C project?

Tags: c, clion

I use Clion 2016.1
Clion creates project with CMakeLists.txt and main.c:

The content of CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(Fir)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(Fir ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

The content of main.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

But it gives:

```
Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again?
```

How to properly declare configuration to run the project

Comment: Have you installed mingw or cygwin with g++, make and others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, I make a new project, build it and choose the project name as executable with this cmake contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(new)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(new ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

[image]